# Is this some kind of parasite crawling about in my yard?

Tags: species-identification, molluscs

[image: it appears like a slug at first glance but looking closer it is not a slug. This molluscs is blackish purple I think but I also seen a gray one once.]

I've been living in **Jamaica** 25 years now and never seen something like this until recently they started popping up around my house at nights by the dozens.  They appear to be **blackish purple or maybe just black** (I think my light has something to do with it), but I recall seeing a grey one once and longest one I've seen so far is about **3 inches long**.

Answer (score 5):

**It looks like a terrestrial ribbon worm.**

[image: terrestrial ribbon worm]

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Terrestrial_Ribbon_Worm_%28Nemertini%29_%2822799575773%29.jpg

Nemertean worms are not leeches, but a different group of worms.  Most are marine but there are a few terrestrial ones.  This depicted worm is from Borneo and other terrestrial nemertean worms are from South Asia also.  But I have read that these can stow away in plants and are turning up in other parts of the world.  I found some small ones in San Diego that I thought were terrestrial leeches but were nemertean worms.

I would be very curious where you are in the world that big ribbon worms are partying in your yard.